# HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER(tls_record.cc:242))

Tags: operating-system, client, handshake

Whenever I want to post data to back-end (nodejs) for registering user and login, this error shows up.
The back-end works fine, I tested it with postman but in flutter i get this error.

```
HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER(tls_record.cc:242))
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have HTTP or HTTPS in your server URL.